Compiling riscv-gnu-toolchain on a computer with an ARM-based Apple M3 chip gives the following error: declaration conflicts
I need the mutlilib support as I am compiling so
./configure --prefix=/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain --with-cmodel=medany --enable-multilib

When I make it soon after I will get the error:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:811:1: 
error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope 
iscntrl(_CharT __c, const locale& __loc)

I tried googling it but got very little out of it, and eventually found a solution in an article about compiling QT:
The reason is an Xcode version issue
Rolling back CLT to 15.1 or earlier will fix this issue.
After doing this and continuing to compile, a new error was encountered, roughly:
/Development/riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-gdb/readline/rltty.c:759:3: error: call to undeclared function 'ioctl'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  ioctl (fildes, TIOCSTOP, 0);

This is not a difficult problem, you can modify the makefile to shut it up or just add the following code to the error file
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

By the way, if you have problems with linking in the compilation, you can quickly get the answer from google, and in order to prevent you from having to make an extra trip, I've also written in this article that:
vim riscv-gcc/gcc/config.host
# 注销96行 97行
96     #out_host_hook_obj=host-darwin.o
97     #host_xmake_file="${host_xmake_file} x-darwin"

Runing:

Apple M3 Pro
macOS sonoma 14.5
CTL version 15.1(after Rolliing back)

